# broken links in Apache Cassandra home page

Tags: cassandra

The link to "materialized views", in the Apache Cassandra home page, indicates that the maxfrinev.com domain expired 243 days ago (???).

Is the documentation of apache cassandra open source being deprecated/abandoned?

Business managers and architects consider this as a high risk for our projects and business depending on cassandra?

The link in question is: http://maxgrinev.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/

I am hoping that this is just an oversight. 
Thank you in advanced for your reply.

Comment: Perhaps you should send an email to the OSS Apache Cassandra mailing list if you would like the link fixed? Looks like just a very old linked blog entry and not actually documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the notice. As Russ said please email the user ML next time. I've updated the website to point to an updated post on materialized views. I wouldn't infer a risk to the C* project based on a single bad link...

Comment: I am worried myself, but I have to follow up on issues of this nature.
Thank you Russ and Jake.

Comment: I did not know where to ask. I will email to the OSS Apache Cassandra mailing list from now on. Thanks